# Cannot deploy application on iPOD - "Your device has an old version of the Developer Disk Image mounted"?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to deploy my XCode project to my iPod touch for the first time.

- I successfully created a provisioning profile and installed in XCode.
- I installed latest XCode 4.(downloaded from Apple site yesterday )
- I upgraded my iPod software to latest (4.3.5)
- I rebooted the iPod as it asks,but nothing happened.

But XCode showing following error

[image]

Any tips?

Comment: Did you "reboot it so that Xcode can mount a newer version thereof"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..if anyone bump into this problem.
Just copy existing Developer Library folder with the version number in the device.(In my case I copied 4.3 folder as "4.3.5 (8L1)"